# How to get Vue.js to to dynamically add forms with django formset

Tags: vue.js, django-forms

I have been struggling trying to get Vue.js to dynamically create the form while updating the ids of the form elements. I am new to Vue.js.

I have tried to have each form as a vue component, but I can't seem to update the ids, or they all seem to have the same id when inspecting with vue dev tools.

I have also tried to nest vue instances, then I am able to get the id's to be correct but then the other functionality doesn't work.

html

```
    <body class="bg-dark">
<!--style="background-color:Black;"-->

        <div class="container-fluid p-4 bg-dark text-white" style="margin-top:74px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="row" id="app">
<!--                        <member-form v-for="member in members" :key="member_form_component_id"></member-form>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" id="add_button_div">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary m-2" type="button" id="id_btn_add_row"
                                v-on:click="add_member">Add Member</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="member-form-template">

        <div class="row" id="form-div-__prefix__">
            <div class="row input-group input-group-md">
                <div class="col border  mx-auto">
                    <input type="text" name="member_set-__prefix__-first_name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off"
                           class="form-control m-2" maxlength="100" id="id_member_set-__prefix__-first_name"
                           v-model="member_first_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col border  mx-auto">
                    <input type="text" name="member_set-__prefix__-last_name" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off"
                           class="form-control m-2" maxlength="100" id="id_member_set-__prefix__-last_name"
                           v-model="member_last_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col border mx-auto">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control m-2" name="member_set-__prefix__-dob" id="id_member_set-__prefix__-dob"
                           v-model="member_dob" @blur="joad_check">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="id_member_button-__prefix__">Delete</button>

            </div>
            <div class="row input-group input-group-md border" id="form-div-__prefix__-joad" v-if="joad_seen">

                <div class="col">To register for a JOAD session select start date:</div>
                <div class="col">
                    <select name="member_set-__prefix__-joad" class="form-control m-2 costs" id="id_member_set-__prefix__-joad" v-model="member_joad">
                        <option value="" selected>None</option>
                        <option value="2020-05-24">2020-05-24</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

js

```
var app1
var form_count = 0
var max_forms
var MemberForm
var MemberFormComponentId = 0
$(document).ready(function() {

    app1 = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data: {
            members: [],
        },
        methods: {
            add_member: function() {

                let v = new Vue({
                    el: "#form-div-" + form_count,
                    created: function() {
                        $("#app").html($("#app").html() + $("#member-form-template").html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_count))
                    },
                    data: {
                        seen: false,
                        first_name: $("#id_member_set-" + form_count + "-first_name"),
                        last_name: $("#id_member_set-" + form_count + "-last_name"),
                        dob_id: $("#id_member_set-" + form_count + "-dob"),
                        joad: $("#id_member_set-" + form_count + "-joad"),
                        form_id: form_count,
                    },
                    methods: {
                        joad_check() {
                            if (this.member_dob === "") {
                                return false
                            }
                            var bd = new Date(this.member_dob);
                            var joad_date = new Date();
                            joad_date.setFullYear(joad_date.getFullYear() - 21);
                            this.joad_seen = (bd > joad_date && bd < new Date())
                        },
                        disable_delete () {
                            $("#id_member_button-"+ this.form_id).prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                    },
                    mounted: function () {
                        if(this.form_id == 0) {
                            $("#id_member_button-"+ this.form_id).prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                    }
                })
                this.members.push(v)
                form_count++
                MemberFormComponentId++
                if( form_count > max_forms) {
                    $("#id_btn_add_row").prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $("#id_btn_add_row").prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    app1.add_member()
})
```